# How to play from A to B in a Video in MediaPlayerElement in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to play a portion of a video, ie. from a point (A) to another point (B). It is obvious to start MediaPlayerElement from point A, then checking the current position of the video using a Timer, and stopping when player reaches end Point (B). But it seems an inefficient method. Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

There isnt any property which can let you **set end position** of your **MediaPlayerElement**, in your application usually there will be only 1 media ( audio/video ) playing. So you can just have a **static Timer** in your app, whenever a new media start playing set its start time and then start the timer ( like you are already doing ) and then after the media ends at your desired positon with help of your timer, just before playing next media, you can **reset the timer**.

Because the timer will be a **singelton** ( a single object ) and u can keep reusing it throughout the lifetime of your application, it will be super efficient this way. the trick here is to make the timer variable as **static** and put it in a static service class which is accessible from anywhere in the app.